# How to quickly calculate the sympy symol within the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sympy

I use pandas, numpy, sympy library in python.
Is there a way to calculate the below for statement faster?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(100 ** 2).reshape(100,100))
x = sp.symbols('x',real = True)
df.loc[99,99] = x

for j in range(99,0,-1):
   for k in range(j-1,-1,-1):
      df.loc[k,j] = df.loc[k+1,j] ** (1/2) * sp.exp(1.5)
      df.loc[j-1,j-1] = df.loc[0,j]
```

I used threading, multiprocessing, numba library for speed improvement.
But always appear Error.

Comment: While `df` starts filled with float zeros, by inserting a sympy `symbol` you changed the dtype of frame (or at least some columns) to object dtype.  Now you've lost all speed advantages of compiled numpy methods.  I expect `numba` has problems with this as well.  We don't recommend mixing sympy and numpy - unless you know what you are doing!

Comment: Thank you. 

But I should use the sympy symbol. 
so if i mix sympy an numpy, i can't improve calculrate speed. is it right? 
if you know another sovle, please teach me.

Comment: Is there any way to use 'x' symbol in numpy?

Comment: I don't understsnd what you are trying to do.  `numpy` is for numeric calculations, especially large arrays.  `sympy` is symbolic, think algebra. You can't use either effectively without some study.

Answer (score 0):

Let's run your code, but with a reasonable size 4 (instead of 100):

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(4 ** 2).reshape(4,4))
   ...: x = sp.symbols('x',real = True)
   ...: df.loc[3,3] = x
   ...: 
   ...: for j in range(3,0,-1):
   ...:    for k in range(j-1,-1,-1):
   ...:       df.loc[k,j] = df.loc[k+1,j] ** (1/2) * sp.exp(1.5)
   ...:       df.loc[j-1,j-1] = df.loc[0,j]
   ...:       

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
                              0                             1  \
0  19.1657532216759*x**0.015625  19.1657532216759*x**0.015625   
1                           0.0   18.2880894824436*x**0.03125   
2                           0.0                           0.0   
3                           0.0                           0.0   

                             2                          3  
0  18.2880894824436*x**0.03125  13.8045741860671*x**0.125  
1   16.6514949636101*x**0.0625   9.48773583635853*x**0.25  
2    13.8045741860671*x**0.125    4.48168907033806*x**0.5  
3                          0.0                          x  

In [9]: df.dtypes
Out[9]: 
0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
dtype: object
```

As I commented, this an object dtype frame.

As a numpy array:

```
In [10]: df.to_numpy()
Out[10]: 
array([[19.1657532216759*x**0.015625, 19.1657532216759*x**0.015625,
        18.2880894824436*x**0.03125, 13.8045741860671*x**0.125],
       [0.0, 18.2880894824436*x**0.03125, 16.6514949636101*x**0.0625,
        9.48773583635853*x**0.25],
       [0.0, 0.0, 13.8045741860671*x**0.125, 4.48168907033806*x**0.5],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, x]], dtype=object)
```

It would be simpler (and probably faster) use arrays directly, rather than pandas:

```
In [11]: arr = np.zeros((4,4),object)
    ...: x = sp.symbols('x',real = True)
    ...: arr[3,3] = x
    ...: 
    ...: for j in range(3,0,-1):
    ...:    for k in range(j-1,-1,-1):
    ...:       arr[k,j] = arr[k+1,j] ** (1/2) * sp.exp(1.5)
    ...:       arr[j-1,j-1] = arr[0,j]
```

But I don't know what's the value of this array.  You can't apply any sympy functions/methods to a numpy array (e.g. no `subs`).  You could do some rudimentary math with the array, so long as `x` implements it, such as 2*arr`, or` arr+arr`.  Even` arr@arr.T`, which ends up using the` +`and`* `properties of`x`.  But all that's done a iterative Python speeds (like lists).

Comment: Thank u. I should syudy rudimentary math! Thank you for your detailed answer.